# Add a word before and after a string

Tags: regex, powershell

How can I add 2 words in front and behind of a regex matched string?

Example:

***hi1,hi2,***6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b3551350e36d2cef84097077a4f5f12e5ee359625ec0f776403895039c4442860fa9968827ab119c8e8362c8a5cbef4389c2c36a08eda30ce091fe9a8e19f9eec0d***,hi3***

Regex to match string: `\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}\b`

String: `6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b3551350e36d2cef84097077a4f5f12e5ee359625ec0f776403895039c4442860fa9968827ab119c8e8362c8a5cbef4389c2c36a08eda30ce091fe9a8e19f9eec0d`

I want to add: `hi1`, `hi2`, `hi3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$&` to reference the match in the replacement string:

```
$s = '6d37...ec0d'
$s -replace '\b[a-f0-9]{64}\b', 'hi1,hi2,$&,hi3'
```

Uppercase characters in the match expression are not required because PowerShell operators (`-replace` in this case) are case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar: (Get-Content "C:\Users\test\Desktop\testing\testing3.csv") | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\b[a-f0-9]{64}\b', 'hi1,hi2,$&,hi3'              $& works

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what to match, here is an example:

```
$str = 'klpo6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b3551350e36d2cef84097077a4f5f12e5ee359625ec0f776403895039c4442860fa9968827ab119c8e8362c8a5cbef4389c2c36a08eda30ce091fe9a8e19f9eec0dputy'
if ($str -match '\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}\b'){
    'hi1,hi2,{0},hi3' -f $matches[0]
}
```